# How make a multi account system? (username, password, etc.)

Tags: c#

I am making a console-based bank application (mostly for learning purposes) and I need to make some sort of array/list/dictionary with a username, password, balance, ID, etc. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right at all, but I already have a command input and half-finished parser. I need to figure out how I'm going to make the account system. At first I thought of making a data structure, like

```
public static struct AccountStruct
    {
        string username;
        string password;
        int balance;
        int ID;
    }
```

And then somehow every time a new account was created, make a structure named "public static AccountStruct Acc#" with # being the number of accounts+1, then define all the values based on user input. But of course you can't name variables/structures based off of others. So I looked into it some more and I discovered Dictionaries, but you can only have two values (as far as I know..?) in them, so I am sort of lost here. Here's the full unfinished code for the bank thing because I know I'm probably doing something wrong here too: http://pastebin.com/HrCNAQKa

Comment: Please don't use mutable structs, create a class with properties instead. You are opening yourself up to major headaches. Also, it should not be marked `static` (and won't compile because you can't have instance members in a static object). Also, looking at your linked code, avoid using the names `Var` and `Func` for your objects, var is a keyword and Func is a very commonly used delegate.

Comment: belongs at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: What's the difference between stackoverflow and programmers.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re making a few mistakes I often see beginners make.

1. [You’re not actually asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/). Stack Overflow is simply not set up to provide interactive tutorials. Try to write some code that demonstrates a specific problem and post that code to the question. Don’t simply provide a link to code; the search can’t find it, and we have no idea if the destination will correspond to the question. Links expire as well.
2. Everything is `static`. That means there can only ever be one of the things you have made static, and every instance is the same one. In your case this means you will never have more than one account.
3. You're using a mutable struct. As Ron Beyer mentioned, such things are the cause of nightmarish problems like variables seeming to be different values simultaneously.

To start, you should define an `Account` class something like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public readonly int ID;
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
    public decimal Balance;

    public Account(int id, string username, string password)
    {
        ID = id;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

Then you can create multiple Accounts:

```
var c1 = new Account(1, "Janet", "Pharos");
var c2 = new Account(2, "Sarah", "Logopolis");
```

While a file or database will probably be needed for a permanent solution, if you’re just testing you can simply store the accounts in a list:

```
var accounts = new List<Account>
{
    c1, c2
};
```

Experiment with the [List methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); they can be used to search for, insert, and remove accounts. If you run into problems, post your code to a new question.

Comment: I'd change the public fields to properties -- might as well start teaching good practices.

Comment: @Daniel I considered that, and it is a better practice, but in my experience too many beginner tutorials use fields, and trying to explain the distinctions will confuse beginners. The List example I linked to uses fields, not properties.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks. I should probably watch a proper C# tutorial before trying to do stuff like this :P Also the pastebin thing was just because I was worried the post would be too long. I've been meaning to actually find out what static meant.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to do this would be to use a relational database (MySQL, etc.), but if you want to just do something for testing purposes you could use a Dictionary. It does only take two parameters, a key and a value. The key could be the user's account number, and the value could be the structure you've created which contains all of the other information.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I made the dictionary: (class Var) `public static Dictionary<int, AccountStruct> AccountDict = new Dictionary<int, AccountStruct>();` but in the function, how do I define the second parameter? I have this: (Class Func) `Var.AccountDict.Add(Var.Accounts, Var.AccountStruct);`

Comment: Sorry, which function are you referring to?